# No title and thumbnail when uploading video using vimeo API

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using vimeo API (with upload access) to uplaod videos to Vimeo
and its working perfectly fine
For that I am using `vimeo's official PHP library`

But video when uploaded to vimeo(using API) has no thumbnail and is named as `untitled`

How to have a video with thumbnail and title on vimeo using (upload API)

Answer (score 0):

The thumbnail will be auto generated once the transcoding is complete, and the title must be set manually through the [PATCH method](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#PATCH/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D)